# C Programming: Chatbot reading several question and answers. How to create multiple key and values?

Tags: c, csv, chatbot, key-value

I have a txt file that contains the questions and answers that a chatbot is supposed to answer as it reads it

My assignment task is that,

```
//knowledge_get() retrieves the response to a question.

int knowledge_get(const char* intent, const char* entity, char* response, 
int n) {

/* to be implemented */

return KB_NOTFOUND;
}
```

How do I create several keys and values so that the chatbot will print if it is under that specify value?

Comment: Now is probably a great time to read a few text-books or take a class or two. Terms you might want to read extra about: *structures*, *loops*, *selection*, *strings*, *string comparisons*, *arrays*, *pointers* and *dynamic allocation*. Which is basically all of basic C.

Comment: Learn first of all, and come up with good baseline data.